# Negative axis drawn on Bar Chart axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I'm building a macro to draw a bar chart using Tikz.

When all the values are 0, tikz draws a negative axis, and I don't know how to prevent this.

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\pgfplotstableread{
sym y
S 0
L 0
XL 0
XXL 0
}\mypoints

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line*=middle,
        axis y line=left,
        axis line style=-,
        ymin = 0,
        ytick distance=1,
        ybar,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        xticklabels from table={\mypoints}{sym},
        xtick=data,
    ]
        \addplot[color=red, fill=red] table [x expr=\coordindex] {\mypoints};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With every value set to 0 ( in `pgfplotstableread`), and even with `ymin=0`, tikz draws a part of the negative axis from -1 to 0.

I'd like to prevent this, in order to have my vertical axis starting at 0.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Try adding `ymax = 1` or whichever value may be useful for you and it should disappear.

Comment: I do not understand, why you want an empty plot. Markus gives the solution. The warning when you compile tells you that it will happen : "Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis y is approximately empty; enlargi
ng it...". So PGFPlots also does not understand the empty plot.